# Smack: Unable to send a message with a Chat created with "Chat chat = mgr.createChat("winnenair",listener);"

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

```
MessageListener listener = new MessageListener(){
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message){
        println message.getBody()
    }
}
ConnectionConfiguration cfg = new ConnectionConfiguration("my-pc",5222);
cfg.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
XMPPConnection con = new XMPPConnection(cfg);
con.connect();
con.login("littlechild","secretpassword");
ChatManager mgr = con.getChatManager();
Chat chat = mgr.createChat("winnenair",listener);
chat.sendMessage("Hello!");
// con.disconnect();
```

I am using this code to send a message to a user named "`winnenair`".

My OpenFire Admin Console does show me (the code) and the user (Spark IM Client) as online. However, when I send a message from the code, it never appears in the IM Client. Both of them are on the same laptop.

Have I done something wrong?

**Extra:**
Both the users have been added to the roster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is confined to this line:

```
Chat chat = mgr.createChat("winnenair",listener);
```

The name "`winnenair`" needs to be "`winnenair@my-pc`". One needs to append the domain to the username.

Comment: The domainpart of the JID was missing, to be correct. See also the javadoc of [createChat](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ChatManager.html#createChat(java.lang.String,%20org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener)).